# react native google maps alternative

Tags: google-maps, openstreetmap, bing-maps, react-native

I have a react native project on android.

I already installed [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps) and all works fine, but I need to run my app on android device **without** google services (such as TomTom navigator).

Is there an alternative to google maps? (bing, openstrett, ecc)
Thanks

Comment: I think there are no libraries for alternative maps in react-native.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Few alternatives for google maps in react native :

- Mapbox - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl
- Yandex Map - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-yandexmapkit

Answer (score -3):

Alternatively, you can create your own component for any map :
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

This gives you full control on moving out to any map sdk and creating your custom native component